# Как сверстать такое?

Tags: html, вёрстка

[image: текст и картинка]

Пыталась, но текст не продолжается на фоне, а остаётся на картинке.

```css
.picture{
  background: url('http://bm.img.com.ua/nxs/img/prikol/images/large/3/9/315193.jpg');
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture">
  <h1>Просто какой-нибудь текст 12345</h1>
</div>
```

, но текст остаётся внутри картинки, а мне надо, чтобы он за неё выходил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно либо 2 блока `div` либо псевдо классы `before`, `after`

Пример с псевдо классом

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/Img/sprites.svg?v=f508971f422f);
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(data:image/x-icon;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Оберните текст в див и отпрозиционирйте если надо. Можно воспользовать и padding
</div>
```

Пример с вложенным блоком

```css
.a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/Img/sprites.svg?v=f508971f422f);
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.a .b {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(data:image/x-icon;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
  </div>

  Оберните в div и отпозиционируйте, если надо
</div>
```

Если нужна прозрачность, делайте PNG с прозрачным фоном

Comment: Тут самое главное, что есть жёлтая картинка на пёстром фоне (я изменила иллюстрацию), на ней - текст. Он должен продолжаться на картинку-фон, а сейчас он заполняет жёлтую картинку.

Comment: это меняется либо left/top и тп свойствами, либо разположением второй картинки

Comment: Я обновил примеры

Answer (score 1):

С помощью свойства [mask-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image)

```css
.text-container {
      border: 1px solid purple;
      position: relative;
width: 600px;
height: 200px;
      margin-left: 50px;
      margin-top: 50px;
 }

.image-container {
height: 400px;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/640/480/');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#text {
  z-index: 100; 
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#im2 {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
  mask-image: gradient(
    linear, left center, right center, 
    color-stop(0.00,  rgba(0,0,0,1)),
    color-stop(1.00,  rgba(0,0,0,0)));
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear, left center, right center, 
    color-stop(0.00,  rgba(0,0,0,1)),
    color-stop(1.00,  rgba(0,0,0,0)));
    
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="text-container">
    <img id=im2 src="http://lorempixel.com/240/480/" >
    <h1 id=text>Текст, более длинный текст. раз - два</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, новую картинку в вопросе. У меня проблема в том, что текст остаётся внутри картинки, как я показала в коде. А надо часть внутри, часть - снаружи. Но ответ всё равно понравился.

Comment: я думал вопрос о градиенте

Comment: Судя по тому, как мне отвечали, все так и подумали. Всё равно спасибо! Очень красивое решение.

Answer (score 1):

Более поддерживаемый вариант будет, если данный переход будет выполнен заранее в графическом редакторе.

Вы можете использовать CSS свойство [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask), но у него поддержка слабовата.

Comment: Тут самое главное, что есть жёлтая картинка на пёстром фоне (я изменила иллюстрацию), на ней - текст. Он должен продолжаться на картинку-фон, а сейчас он заполняет жёлтую картинку.